# Iterate through enum in Silverlight 4

Tags: c#, silverlight, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iterating through an enumeration in Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038234/iterating-through-an-enumeration-in-silverlight)

Is there a way to iterate through all values in an Enum in Silverlight with C#?

I know WPF allows you to use the System.Enum.GetType(Type) method, but this is not available in Silverlight.

Thanks,
Seth

Comment: @Ani - You're right, I missed that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetEnumValues<T>()
    {
        return typeof(T)
            .GetFields()
            .Where(x => x.IsLiteral)
            .Select(field => (T)field.GetValue(null));
    }
```

usage

```
        foreach (var bindingFlag in GetEnumValues<BindingFlags>())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(bindingFlag);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public static List<T> GetList<T>(Type enumType)
    {
        List<T> output = new List<T>();

        var fields = from field in enumType.GetFields()
                     where field.IsLiteral
                     select field;


        foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
        {
            object value = field.GetValue(enumType);
            output.Add((T) value);
        }

        return output;

    }
```

Call it like this:

```
List<MyEnum> myList = GetList<MyEnum>(typeof(MyEnum))
```