# How to pass Enum as argument

Tags: c#, silverlight, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iterating through an enumeration in Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038234/iterating-through-an-enumeration-in-silverlight)

I came up with a handy little function that gets me the count of an enum (I know it won't work properly with all enums).  Rather than hard coding the Enum into the function such that I have to write a seprate function for each Enum I want to use it with, I wanted to pass the enum in as an argument but I am having difficulty figuring out how to do this.

Here is the code:

```
    private enum MyColors { Red, Green, Blue }

    private Int32 GetEnumCount()
    {
        Int32 i = 0;
        while (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyColors), (MyColors)i))
        {
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }
```

---

UPDATE

I came up with this as the answer in the end:

```
    private Int32 GetEnumCount(Type enumType)
    {
        Int32 i = 0;
        while (Enum.IsDefined(enumType, i))
        {
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }
```

Comment: Btw, the 2nd-highest answer on that page is the one I recommend.

Comment: This approach would only work where the enum values are contiguous.  A `Flags` attributed enum would typically have gaps in the integers used so this approach would fail.  Perhaps you could explain why you need this?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative (although clearly this has already been answered) if you start the first one with 0 then add one on at the end called count then you can use that, eg:

```
enum MyColour
{
     Blue = 0,
     Red,
     Green,
     ColourCount
}
```

Comment: this is a useful one to bear in mind

Answer (score 1):

This can be done, but there's some additional work needed to make it work with unusal enums:

```
private static ulong GetEnumContiguousCount(Type enumType)
{
    var underlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(enumType);
    ulong i;
    for (i = 0; Enum.IsDefined(enumType, Convert.ChangeType(i, underlyingType, null)); ++i) {}
    return i;
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/Serji

Comment: +1: The need to cope with a different underlying types makes sense, but returning `ulong` doesn't, `int` would do and would be easier to use.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: You're probably right, but I didn't both to look up the maximum number of members of an enum.

Answer (score 0):

You should take the enum `Type` as an argument, and remove the cast to `(MyColors)`.

In non-Sliverlight, you can also just replace your function with

```
Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Length
```

Comment: -1 for copying my answer in your edit!

Comment: @Noldorin: I wrote this answer before you did, and I wrote the edit before I saw your answer.

Comment: No, you did not When I posted my answer, your `Enum.GetValues` bit was *not* included. I refreshed 30 seconds later and it was. You even called your enum type exactly the same thing...

Comment: I wrote the edit without refreshing the page; I hadn't seen your answer.  `MyEnum` is an obvious name; note my lack of `var`.

Comment: Notice the Silverlight tag.  There is not getValues in Silverlight for Enums.

Comment: -9999 You both copied the docs on Enum.GetValues(). For Shame!!!